# CSS Class Merging

Tags: css, html

Can someone shed some light on this issue?  The expected result does NOT appear to be happening...  Am I correct in my assumptions?

```
.float-right{
  float:right;
}

.header{
   (stuff we don't care about)
}

.header img .float-right {
  display:inline;
  margin:0 0 0 0.5em;
}
```

I *THOUGHT* that would mean that a < img > tag inside a < div class="header" > would get:

```
float:right;
display:inline;
margin:0 0 0 0.5em;
```

*IF* the < img > tag was class="float-right"

Is this correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the result that you want, it should be

```
.header img.float-right
```

(no space)

Answer (score 1):

No. `.header img .float-right` means any tag with the float-right class that is a descendant of an img tag which is in turn the descendant of a tag with the header class.

Answer (score 0):

> IF the < img > tag was class="float-right"

To acheive that there should be no space

```
 .header img.float-right {
```

As it is now, it's looking for

```
 [an element with class "float-right"] [inside an img] [inside an element with class header]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what will happen if you remove the space between img and .float-right in your stylesheet.